# How to auto break text in an HTML cell?

Tags: html, css, cell

I am generating an HTML page which is later converted as a PDF showing a certain grid of data. For that I am using an HTML table. The table used to stretch whenever the text is long causing half of it to disappear from the PDF (to the left).

I managed to fix the table width using `table-layout: fixed`. Now I am facing the case where the text is either showing on top of each other or it no longer visible if it is too long. Here is a sample:

- Open this link : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_table-layout
- Check the second table
- Add many zeros to the second column of the second table and click `Submit code`
- Check how the table looks like.

I am looking for a convenient way to auto-add a line break whenever the text reaches the cell boundaries.

Comment: `word-wrap: break-all;` is the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the words to be breaked according to the boundaries like the below pic

[image]

Use the **CSS** code

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `word-break` CSS property.

#### Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ETLsB/)

#### HTML

```
<table class="ex2" border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="5%">1000000000000000000000000000</td>
        <td width="95%">1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
table.ex2 {
    table-layout:fixed;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```